# Apply Ken Burns and GLSL Transition effects to video - command line

Tags: linux, video, command-line-interface, video-effects

I have an mp4 video that I need to apply the Ken Burns effect and GLSL Transition effects between images. Are there any command line tools to accomplish this? I am building an automated process and need something able to run on the command line. It doesn't matter what it is, as long as it's able to run in the terminal, I can use it. An example of what I'm looking for is found here: http://greweb.me/diaporama/#example/0 in the Greweb's Garden example video or another example is here: http://www.circlepix.com/media/tours/2015/nov/12/6K5NNH/video-genie/ (depending on your connection speed, this one might not transition smoothly)